# How do I keep position when concatenation completes?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

What I have is a menu of frequent solutions. I want to be able to click the menu item and have it add that text to the rich textbox while I am editing.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + ToolStripMenuItem2.Text
```

This does the trick for adding the text to RichTextBox1, with only one drawback. It returns the cursor to the home position. How can I keep from that happening if at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
RichTextBox1.Focus()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the Length of the Text in your RichTextBox.

i.e.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + ToolStripMenuItem2.Text    
RichTextBox1.Focus()
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
```

From above Link:

> You can programmatically move the caret within the text box by setting the SelectionStart to the position within the text box where you want the caret to move to and set the SelectionLength property to a value of zero (0).

Answer (score 0):

```
RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
```